# Last chance API call on Lambda function timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm having an issue where sometimes my Lambda function times out. I'd like to know if there's a way I can detect that timeout so I can send a message (via HTTP REST) to my app, so the user can be notified they uploaded too large a file. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: All calls made to AWS Lambda must complete execution within 300 seconds. You could pass a message just before the time-out.

Comment: What runtime are you using? Nodejs, Java, Python? The context provides a getRemainingTimeInMillis() function where you can temporarily check how much time is left.

Comment: @AliEntertainment That's exactly what I'm asking. I have my timeout set to 120 seconds. I'd like to somehow have my script know when that timeout is reached.

Comment: @hellomichibye Node.js. I'll have to look into how I can poll `getRemainingTimeInMillis()` every 5 seconds or so.

Comment: @hellomichibye Did you want to make your response an official answer?

Comment: @ffxsam yes. I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context provides a getRemainingTimeInMillis() function where you can temporarily check how much time is left.